# Typeorm column value from sanitized other column value

Tags: typescript, entity, typeorm

I have this `User` class that uses typeorm. Is it possible to use the column transformer

```
@Entity()
class User {
  @Index(ColumnIndex.UNIQUE_EMAIL, { unique: true })
  @IsEmail()
  @Column({ type: PostgresColumn.VARCHAR })
  email: ReadOnlyColumn<string>

  @Field()
  @IsEmail()
  @Column({ type: PostgresColumn.VARCHAR })
  authoredEmail: string
}
```

Given a corresponding repository I'd like to be able to create like this:

```
user.create({
 authoredEmail: "Thomas.mEoW@gmail.com"
})
```

Somehow i'd like to "normalizeEmail" the `email` column `Sanitizer.normalizeEmail(str, isLowercase);`. Is this possible to take place in the Entity using transformer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do anything in a transformer:

```
@Column({ 
  transformer: {
    to: (value: string) => value.toLowerCase(),
    from: (value: string) => value
  }
 })
email: string
```